# Can we use propositional logic to prove set identities?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, propositional-calculus

For instance, to prove that $A \cup (B \cap C)=(A \cup B)\cap(A\cup C) $, can we use the definition of union and intersection, namely $A \cup B=\{x\mid x \in A \lor x \in B\}$ and $A \cap B=\{x\mid x \in A \land x \in B\}$, and derive the set or propositions $A(x)=x \text{ is in }A , B(x)=x \text{ is in } B, C(x)=x \text{ is in } C$.

Then, using logic, would it be sufficient to prove the following?
$A(X) \lor (B(x) \land C(x)) \equiv (A(x) \lor B(x)) \land (A(x) \lor C(x)) $

Thanks!

Comment: similar objects but not the same. It seems that the ensembles demonstration you suggest needs the logic equivalence but not the converse

Comment: @user1354784: How about $(x \in A \cup (B \cap C)) \equiv (x \in A \vee x \in B \cap C) \equiv (x \in A \vee (x \in B \wedge x \in C)) \equiv ((x \in A \vee x \in B) \wedge (x \in A \vee x \in C)) \equiv (x \in A\cup B \wedge x \in A\cup C) \equiv (x \in (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C))$ ?